# Where do I find information about sap.m.Tree control?

Tags: tree, sapui5

The [sap.m.Tree](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Tree.html) entry in the API reference seems to be incomplete. There are methods on the tree control which are used in official examples but not included in the API reference (e.g. expandToLevel()-method in [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TreeInitialExpandState/code)).

I am using this control in my app and need some more information on how to use it. Specifically how to select an item by a given BindingContext or how to get an array of all items (the getItems()-method of the sap.m.ListBase seems to only return an array of the visible items in the tree).

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I guess the [source code of sap.m.Tree](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Tree.js) is the only way to see all its methods. Not sure about how to get all items.

Comment: I just updated my above comment as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48251919/5846045). For other distinct questions, please create new questions accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of UI5 [version 1.50](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/3124857bcb803172f94c4ae86dcd517134d14fc6), The missing documentation parts of APIs, such as `expandToLevel` and `collapseAll`, are now publicly visible in the [API Reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Tree/methods/expandToLevel).